# Error "Element should have been "select" but was "div" " in java code

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Здравствуйте, пишу тесты на Java используя Test NG. 
Столкнулась с такой проблемой: 
Есть метод выбора value с выпадающего списка (см. ниже пример)

```
public void selectItemByValue(WebElement element, int index) {
    Select dropdown = new Select(element);
    dropdown.selectByIndex(index);
}
```

Вот участок кода, с которого мне нужно выбрать один элемент (Нужно выбрать employee)  -  http://prntscr.com/i8qrgj

При запуске теста - выдает ошибку -
'org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"

Немогу найти решение, помогите пожалуйста кто уже сталкивался с этим. (Что ошибка означает я понимаю, а как решить - не совсем)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже выяснила - это у меня Semantic drop-down list, где каждый вариант выбора - предоставлен как div...
Существуют ли вообще универсальные методы выбора варианта с выпадающего списка такого типа или лучше использовать обычные методы нажатия на кнопку и стучаться к элементу через локаторы?

Answer (score 0):

Тип `Select` можно использовать только для элементов `select`, на сколько знаю. Так как у вас `div`, то напишите свой класс для подобных выпадающих списков. Либо, возможно, у же есть что-то готовое, если эта штука распространена.

Выбирать можно по атрибуту `data-value`: сначала кликаем по списку, чтобы он "вывалился", а потом по элементу с нужным `data-value`